# Unit Testing Email Delivery in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, email

Can someone recommend a method for doing automated unit testing for email delivery? I have a library which makes web service calls to an email service provider, and I want to test delivery to my test mailbox. Ultimately, I also need to test the email content for expected values.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be misplaced energy to test the service you are using.  The service should be testing itself and is ultimately responsible for trying to reach 100% uptime. What you can do is create well structured code that is easy to test the service you are using.

I think the term for this is called dependency injection

If you are using an api and they provide a python library for it you can mock their python library.  This can be done using the builtin [mock](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock) library ( i think it is in standard library python 3.x)

A quick example of how to do this:

```
class AnAPILibraryProvidedByEmailServiceProvider:
   def send_mail(address, message):
     # make some rest calls to their service
     return 200 # success mail code

your_function(email_service, email, message):
    email_service.send_mail(email, message)
```

By taking the service as a parameter it is easy to mock the service

```
class TestService:
  def send_mail(address, message):
     return 200

class TestServiceFailedSend:
  def send_mail(address, message):
     return 500
```

You can create test services that return all sorts of responses and make sure your code does not break.

If you absolutely need to test delivery of your email, python provides `smtp` in standard library that you could use to programmatically access your email server..

Answer (score 0):

If this "email service provider" web service is in your code, then usually you mock it, and verify that your code for sending email calls the appropriate methods with expected parameters. If not, then provide a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)/[proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) in front of it so you can mock them, and verify the behaviour of your code exactly as in the first case.